# Strongest negative emotions?

Tags: psychology

I want to write a book, and the main character will go through negative emotions mainly. My question is: what are the 3/4 or more *strongest basic negative emotions* (like anger for example) I could describe through the main character ?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: This does not appear to be on-topic for worldbuilding. Perhaps you should direct this question to the [Writers SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in what is called a [wheel of emotions](http://study.com/cimages/multimages/16/Plutchik-wheel.png).

[image: Here is the wheel of emotions.]

It can very well describe positive and negative emotions, as well as their strength. This way you can express gradually your main character's feelings.

If you are in thirst of more adjectives for it, I would recommend you [this wheel](http://inkwellideas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/emotionwheel.png), with even more adjectives for each category. You cannot feel empty-handed about words with those resources.